# C++ Pass class member function to other class

Tags: c++

I have a class `wrapper` which holds an intance of the class `trigger`. I want to pass a member function of `wrapper` to `trigger` so that, on some event `trigger` can call such function, having effect on the instance of `wrapper`. It is possible to do that?

My idea of code is something like this:

```
class trigger {
public:
    trigger(int trigger_thr): _trigger_thr(trigger_thr){};
    trigger &operator+=(int v) {
        _trigger_value += v;
        check_trigger();
        return *this;
    }

    void set_callback(someType f){
        _f = f;
    }

private:
    int _trigger_value;
    int _trigger_thr;

    someType _f;

    void check_trigger() {
        if (_trigger_value >= _trigger_thr)
            _f();
    }
};

class wrapper {
public:
    wrapper() {
        _t.set_callback(someType some_function)
    }

private:
    void some_function() {/* do something */}

private:
    trigger _t;
}
```

Comment: Just substitute `someType` with `std::function`.

Comment: I have tried but I get the error: 

Reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?

Comment: If you need to have a general solution (albeit heavier weight), [Boost Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/signals2.html) may be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace someType with `std::function<void()>`, and in `wrapper`'s constructor, give the trigger a lambda that calls the appropriate method :

```cpp
// in class trigger
void set_callback(std::function<void()> f) {
    _f = f;
}

// in class wrapper
wrapper() {
    _t.set_callback([this](){ some_function(); });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it was so simple!

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to refer to a member function is `&wrapper::some_function`. That creates a pointer to the member function, which can be passed to another function and stored. Its type will be `void (wrapper::*)()` and to call that function you have to have an object of type `wrapper` (you can't just call a member function on thin air, you need an object). So to pass that to the trigger class you'd *also* need to pass a `wrapper*` on which the function can be called. Given a pointer `p` of type `wrapper*` and a pointer to member `m` of type `void (wrapper::*)()` you would call it as `(p->*m)()` which is one of the ugliest and hardest to remember forms of C++ syntax.

Alternatively, you can use a lambda expression to create a closure object that captures the object and calls the member function:

```
set_callback( [this] { this->some_function(); } );
```

To store that closure object in a member variable you'll need to use a `std::function<void()>` which can store any callable object that can be called with no arguments.

So change the function parameter and member from `someType` to `std::function<void()>` and then use a lambda expression when calling `set_callback`. Then you can just call that as `_f()` as in your current code.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation!